# Comparing two groups, consisting of same population

Tags: biostatistics, paired-data

Suppose I have a sample population. I define obesity by three definitions i.e. On basis of BMI, Body Fat % and Waist circumference. I apply these definitions to the whole population.

Now I have three different groups of obese people, but all groups consist of same population, but proportions vary due to definition used. I want to compare the demographics of these groups e..g. Whether one group had taller height or greater age ?. How do I do that ? Which test do I run? Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting question. There may be some subjects which may be different from one group to another. Comparing three groups at a time is not feasible as three groups are not independent of each other. However, two groups can be compared at a time for their demographics.
While comparing two groups, as a first step, remove the common subjects and then compare the mean weight or height of remaining subjects. This will give you an idea whether one group include more taller people or shorter subjects as  compared to other group..